# Android & iPhone sound recording

Tags: android, iphone, audio, audio-recording

I am going to record the sound through Android and iPhone. I know that iPhone Support aif and caf format to record the sound while Android Support 3GP and amr formate to record sound.

Now, I want to know that which format is best to record sound in both environments? I am going to store that sound format to server and then will use it later. Now it is necessary that both the sound have same format, that's why I want the information regarding the format supported in both environment to record and play sound.

Is it possible to record sound and play it in both the environment?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **MP3**. We can play in Android and iPhone.We are doing so to play Audio file. One more Suggestion for Recording Audio file , always use **Media Recorder** for capturing audio since it consume less size.

But using Media Recorder you can set only following formats :

1. **MPEG_4**
2. **RAW_AMR**
3. **THREE_GPP**

*So do some stuffs to convert it to **MP3***

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. But I also like to record the Sound in both environment. So which format is suitable for both ?

Comment: and if i use mp3 then in Iphone i have to convert it in to mp3 as because iPhone records in acf or aif formate. right ?

Comment: Whether you are uploading Audio to Server?

Comment: Actually i am recording the Sound in Device and Uploading it to the Server. Now that Sound is used by any environment like iPhone or Android. Hope you got my Point.

Comment: Okay then no pblm. Ask them to convert to .mp3 for Android and for iPhone. They will be uploading to Amazon kind of server and give http link for you my guess. So ask them to upload in mp3 format so both Android and iPhone can use it to play